# How to edit Date format with @SerializableName in Gson?

Tags: java, gson, date-format

I use Google `Gson` to map data from a `json` file in `Java`. But I encounter an error in the date format.

That's the mistake I saw;

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Sat May 18 15:30:07 +0000 2019
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:87)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:75)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
at app.producer.TwitterKafkaProducer.run(TwitterKafkaProducer.java:75)
at app.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["Sat May 18 15:30:07 +0000 2019"]: Invalid number: Sat 
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:274)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:85)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: Sat 
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parseInt(ISO8601Utils.java:311)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:129)
... 11 more
```

This is where I serialized the incoming json:

```
@SerializedName("created_at")
private Date createdAt;
```

My json object:

```
{
 "created_at": "Sat May 18 16:11:36 +0000 2019",
 "id": 1129781592514355205
}
```

I noticed that the error was caused by the failure of the formats. But in my research on how to fix this, I have no conclusions. I'd appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: Sat
```

It seems that your Gson is not correctly configure for input format `Sat May 18 15:30:07 +0000 2019` so you should do something like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").create();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I got rid of the error you mentioned but I get an error again this way `Exception in thread “main” com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string : “Thu Apr 11 08:57:37 + 0000 2019” `

Comment: @Fatih It seems that your string is wrong. I see a space between + and 0000 in your input string which is incorrect. `+ 0000` should change to `+0000`

Comment: @Fatih There is a space in the exception you paste here!

Comment: Yeah, it's my fault. The error looks like this: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Wed Oct 20 05:38:55 +0000 2010" `

Comment: @Fatih would you please add your json or part of the json that contains this date?

Comment: I added json object to my question.

Comment: @Fatih, I tested the code. there is no problem in it. I guess you have other problems. the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` told you that you are converting a date to a number. please also add the code where you convert input to object. `gson.fromJson`

Comment: `Data data = gson.fromJson(queue.take(), Data.class);` `queue.take()` returns the json file I share